# bundled jquery in theme js not working with wp_localize_script

Tags: jquery, seo, wp-register-script, wp-localize-script

I've bundled jquery in my theme js using grunt-uglify. Now I want to prevent wp jquery from loading since I don't need 2 jquery versions and want to save unnecessary requests.
This is what I have:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/build/scripts/app.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
});

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    global $wp_query;
    wp_localize_script('jquery', 'ajaxpagination', array(
        'ajaxurl'      => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'query_vars'   => json_encode($wp_query->query),
        'is_search'    => is_search(),
        'current_page' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    ));
});
```

I named the `$handle` of `wp_register_script` jquery aswell so the dependencies will load. But for some reason, the CDATA/script tag from `wp_localize_script` will not be rendered once I register my script as jquery.

I've already tried

- enqueueing without registering it first
- deregistering jquery without dequeuing it first

Comment: May you try to add priority in your `add_action` ?

Comment: Why are you changing `jquery` to be your script? Just give your script its own name and enqueue/localize that. If plugin compatibility is a concern then you shouldn't be bundling your own copy.

Comment: @JacobPeattie as stated, I want to save requests so I bundle jquery together with my theme js. So the theme js basically is jquery

Comment: @Jean-RémiLARCELET-PROST adding a priority in `add_action` sadly does not change the outcome

Comment: There are plugins for minifying and combining scripts and styles, I'd suggest you only include code that's yours and minify with a plugin.

Comment: May be use jquery slim and avoid uglifying jquery in your scripts, that's one more request, that's not much and probably be in cache for most people if you use google apis CDN.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `wp_localize_script` with **jquery**. this function use the `WP_Scripts::localize()` function which have a condition right in the start.

You can see it in the file \wp-includes\class.wp-scripts.php line 414

```
if ( $handle === 'jquery' )
    $handle = 'jquery-core';
```

You can do something else like add the script with other action like `wp_head` if your script is in the `<head>` or `wp_print_footer_scripts` if its in the footer.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/build/scripts/app.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
});

add_action('wp_head', function() {
    global $wp_query;

    $my_object = array(
        'ajaxurl'      => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'query_vars'   => json_encode($wp_query->query),
        'is_search'    => is_search(),
        'current_page' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page'     => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    );
    ?>
    <script>
        var ajaxpagination = <?php echo wp_json_encode($my_object); ?>
    </script>
    <?php
}, 0, 1);
```